# How to work with old 3.5" pancake box in stucco for exterior wall light?

Tags: electrical, lighting, exterior

The 3.5-inch round pancake box is a bit proud of the stucco.  I've installed a new exterior wall light but its not flush to the wall.  This is not protected from sideways rain or fog.   Is their a contraption I can get to make this (generic) light work?  Should I consider a standard 4" round box?  (I'd hire for a new box, I don't think I can DIY stucco work).

And yes, I need to plug the red screw holder.

[image: light attached to wall]
[image: pancake box 1]
[image: pancake box 2]

Answer (score 3):

I would use a mounting block (like they do for installing fixtures on siding and other uneven surfaces)

The block will make the electrical box recessed so you can then mount the light fixture flush. Make sure you caulk all the gaps around the block and the light fixture.

Here's a typical install (on siding but it will work on stucco)

[image]

Comment: Depending on the thickness of the block, I like to use foam weatherstripping tape inside, in an inverted U shape.  Doesn't need to go all the way around, just from the top down to the bottom of the box.